# Каким описать сложные формулы в комментариях?

Tags: java, javadoc

Каким способом можно описать сложные формулы в комментариях?

Comment: Лучший вариант - сделать несколько последовательных вызовов функций, которые сделают формулу достаточно понятной.

Comment: Приведите пример сложной формулы в вопросе и то как она должны быть в документации в идеале?

Comment: В том же mapple-4+ сложнейшие формулы можно было написать одной строчкой обычными символами. например http://lib.qrz.ru/files/images/soft/book13/glava_1/32.gif Можно в гуле набрать mapple 4 картинки - там большое разнообразие сложных формул.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании JavaDoc в IDE IntellijIdea автоматически будет предложено описать и все принимаемые методом параметры, и возвращаемое значение. Соответственно, если переменными подставляемые в формулу будут параметры метода - то будет все очень аккуратно. Если же формула слишком большая/сложная для одного метода, то ее можно разбить на несколько методов поменьше и к каждому добавить соответствующий JavaDoc.

```
/**
 * Get WEBSITE name  
 * @param address  http://www.website.ru/         
 * @return         website
 */
```